# API key and discovered Google sheets functions

Tags: authentication, google-api, google-sheets-api, api-key

This question is about authenticating using an API key when using Python to write to a Google sheet.  Following the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) example, I'm "discovering" the API using an URL:

```
service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', discoveryServiceUrl=
    'https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4',
    developerKey=APIKEY)
```

Passing an API key this way seems to work (it throws no exception.)  After that, I try to update the spreadsheet with `batchUpdate`:

```
service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SHEETID,
    body={'requests': requests}).execute()
```

This throws a 401 HTTP error: "Request is missing required authentication credential."  Other functions like `values().clear()` result in the same error.

How can I pass an API key to discovered Python functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your `service` is correct. The problem is that Sheets API for using POST and PUT methods cannot be used using API key. In order to use them, please use access token by OAuth2. I knew this by my experiences. Although I had looked for the document about this at that time, I had not been able to find it. I'm sorry.

On the other hand, you can use Sheets API for GET method using API key. For example, you can retrieve values using API key by the following sample. In order to use this, please share the Spreadsheet. When the Spreadsheet is not shared, "The caller does not have permission" is returned. If API key is not used for this, "The request is missing a valid API key" is returned. This indicates that API key is required.

```
service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', discoveryServiceUrl=
    'https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4',
    developerKey=APIKEY)
res = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=SHEETID, range='sheet1!A1:A1').execute()
```

If this is not useful for you and I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks!  I had hoped to use an API key as a simple alternative to write to the sheets. Oauth makes the installation procedure a lot harder? The admin will have to manually generate the oauth token for each server.

Comment: @Andomar About the OAuth process, users have to manually authorize only once. By this, a refresh token can be retrieved, the access token can be retrieved using the refresh token. This flow might be a bit hard. If you want to easily write the sheet using like API key, I would like to propose the server using Web Apps of Google Apps Script. By using the Web Apps, the admin prepares the server. Users can access and write the sheets easily by accessing to Web Apps. Also it can make users display the Google login screen for the security. If you need, I think that I can discuss about this.

Comment: Just got oauth2 to work, good to hear the token will be refreshed!  If I read the [the web app introduction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) correctly, it requires our server to be reachable from the internet, which is not an option for this problem. Thanks for the suggestion, it looks very interesting!

Comment: @Andomar Welcome. I'm glad I could be useful. Feel free to tell me if you need a sample.