# Read/Write Google sheet via Server without using OAuth

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Tried going through the internet and [google docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java) they provide OAuth way only. Is there a way to read/write to google sheets with API Key and not OAuth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, Credential object from google-oath-client module can help. Download the .p12 file from the google account. Code for reading a google sheet without OAUth prompt below.  This can also be used to write or append sheets with some modification :

```
package com.mycomp;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.ValueRange;
import com.nm.vernacular.services.SpreadSheetsService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by ankushgupta & modified for SO.
 */

public class GoogleSheetsReader {

    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String KEY_FILE_LOCATION = "<Name of p12 file>.p12";
    private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "<email of google service account>";
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Sheets API";

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GoogleSheetsReader.class);

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If there is no client_secret.
     */
    private Credential getCredentials() throws URISyntaxException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        //Reading Key File
        URL fileURL = GoogleSheetsReader.class.getClassLoader().getResource(KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
        // Initializes an authorized analytics service object.
        if(fileURL==null) {
            fileURL = (new File("/resources/"+ KEY_FILE_LOCATION)).toURI().toURL();
        }
        // Construct a GoogleCredential object with the service account email
        // and p12 file downloaded from the developer console.
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        return new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(fileURL.toURI()))
                .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Object[]> readSheet(String nameAndRange, String key, int[] returnRange) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        final String spreadsheetId = key;
        final String range = nameAndRange;
        try {
            Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials())
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .build();

            ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
                    .get(spreadsheetId, range)
                    .execute();
            List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();

            int a = returnRange.length;
            List<Object[]> result = new LinkedList<>();

            if (values == null || values.isEmpty()) {
                return Collections.emptyList();
            } else {
                for (List row : values) {
                    if(row.size() >= a) {
                        Object[] objArr = new Object[a];
                        for(int i=0;i<a;i++) {
                            objArr[i] = row.get(returnRange[i]);
                        }
                        result.add(objArr);
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception while reading google sheet", ex);
        } finally {

        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     GoogleSheetsReader reader = new GoogleSheetsReader();
     reader.readSheet("<Sheet Name>!A2:B", "<sheets key from URL>", new int[]{0, 1});
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The OP is asking how to WRITE to the google sheet without using OAuth.

Comment: @JohnHenckel : the question is around how to read/write without using OAuth token. And the answer above shows "How to read" without OAuth. Same can be used to write as well. Bottomline is "Not use OAuth".

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing), when your application requests public data, the request doesn't need to be authorized, but does need to be accompanied by an identifier, such as an API key.

> Every request your application sends to the Google Sheets API needs to identify your application to Google. There are two ways to identify your application: using an OAuth 2.0 token (which also authorizes the request) and/or using the application's API key. Here's how to determine which of those options to use:
>
> - If the request requires authorization (such as a request for an individual's private data), then the application must provide an OAuth 2.0 token with the request. The application may also provide the API key, but it doesn't have to.
> - **If the request doesn't require authorization (such as a request for public data), then the application must provide either the API key or an OAuth 2.0 token, or both—whatever option is most convenient for you.**

However, there are some scopes which require OAuth authorization. Check this link: [Access Google spreadsheet API without Oauth token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48747530/access-google-spreadsheet-api-without-oauth-token?rq=1/).

Comment: How to send the API Key in the form of Java code? A Curl request or using Google API. Any example would help

Answer (score 0):

Using API key, you can ***read*** from google sheets, but only if the sheet is shared with public.

However to ***write*** to google sheets, you must you OAuth.  [See this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48767368/1812732)